# Link Command Button to VBA in another Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Have an Excel file for different days of the year. also have a master excel file. Would like to create a link button from the day excel files to the VBA in the Master file. So if need to change some code, I can change it in the master file and the day files will run the new code from the master file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, in an open workbook called "Master.xlsm", you have a macro called `test`:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox "in master"
End Sub
```

and that you have a forms control button on a sheet in another open workbook (perhaps "Daily.xlsx"), then you can assign the macro to that button as:
[image]

If you subsequently open just "Daily.xlsx" without first opening "Master.xlsm", you will get the 
[image]
message (due to the link to "Master.xlsm").  Irrespective of whether you say "Update" or "Don't Update", "Master.xlsm" will be automatically opened when you click the button, and the `test` macro will be executed.